# How to get multiple pages with Dompdf

Tags: php, magento, dompdf

I'm using `dompdf` in Magento 2 to download the multiple PDFs for an invoice but getting only one page. Can someone please help me?

```
$domPdf = new Dompdf();
$domPdf->loadHtml($html);
$domPdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$domPdf->render();
```

This is the code to convert to PDF.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it requires additional work to realize multi page. You have to custom style your HTML string used for the loadHtml function to support multi page. For example:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      this is page 1
    </div>
    <div class="page">
      this is page 2
    </div>
    <div class="page">
      this is page 3
    </div>
  </body>

  <style>
    .page {
       page-break-after: always;
    }
    .page:last-child {
       page-break-after: unset;
    }
  </style>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot....i have one more query how can i get each div in one page